# Search table with 30 million records

Tags: mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have sample mysql database with only 1 table ( InnoDB)  that has the following columns

- Id int PK
- Description TEXT

table has more than 30 million records and description field has length up to 1000 character.

What is the most efficient way to make a search for some records in this table? 
i need for example description that starts with / end with / contains.

When i run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Description like '%abc'
```

it takes too long time because the like operator scan all table records 
I google and found that there is something called Full TEXT Index

I add the index using the following command

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `DescriptionIndex` (`Description` ASC)
```

they when i try to execute a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MATCH (`Description`) AGAINST ('"The sea is awesome"')
```

some times it takes long time and other time works good based on the value in against parameter , i could not identify the problem

I need to know if i miss something or there is better way to implement search.

Comment: The search you want to do is quite difficult in MySQL.  You could "fake" `matches` by putting special "tokens" at the beginning and end -- but that assumes that what you want to search for are complete words.  The best solution is something like a GIN index; but MySQL doesn't support that (it is available in Postgres).

Comment: Thanks @gordonlinoff  but what people usually do when they have millions of records in MYSQL ? can you explain what you mean by putting special tokens ?

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff   , but what people usually do when they have millions of records in MYSQL ? can you explain what you mean by putting special tokens ?

Comment: . . In most applications, searching using B-trees or words (full text) is sufficient.